# How to grab the current users "firstname" from firebase store. Swift 5

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I did more trial and error and a bit of online research and this is what I came back with:

```
func presentWelcomeMessage() {
    
               //Get specific document from current user
               let docRef = Firestore.firestore()
                  .collection("users")
                  .whereField("uid", isEqualTo: Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "")

               // Get data
               docRef.getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in
                   if let err = err {
                       print(err.localizedDescription)
                   } else if querySnapshot!.documents.count != 1 {
                       print("More than one document or none")
                   } else {
                       let document = querySnapshot!.documents.first
                       let dataDescription = document?.data()
                       guard let firstname = dataDescription?["firstname"] else { return }
                       self.welcomeLabel.text = "Hey, \(firstname) welcome!"
                   }
               }
```

It works, but am not sure if it is the most optimal solution.

Comment: Probably because the field stored in Firestore is `firstName` not `firstname` or the field `firstname` does not exist within that document. Check your Firestore for those two issues first.

Comment: It's in there as "firstname." I am wondering if it is not finding the uid that it was logged in with because I changed root view controller. Do I need to store the uid on local storage when logging in?

Comment: You can always get the current logged in users uid with the code in your question. However.  if the uid was nil, or if there was an error or if the document was not found the No Name would not show up in the UI with self.welcomeLable.text as it won't get to that line of code. Keep in mind that nil is different than No Name, so you should first ensure that line of code is executing `let welcomeName = doc.get...` I would also suggest adding `print(document)` right after the `if` closure and inspect what prints to console - that would be revealing. Try that an edit your question with the results.

Answer (score 1):

First I should say firstname is not really the best way to store a var. I would recommend using firstName instead for readability. I also recommend getting single documents like I am, rather than using a whereField.

An important thing to note is you should create a data model like I have that can hold all of the information you get.

Here is a full structure of how I would get the data, display it, and hold it.

```
struct UserModel: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: String
    var firstName: String

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
       case id
       case firstName
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

class UserDataManager: ObservableObject {
    private lazy var authRef = Auth.auth()
    private lazy var userInfoCollection = Firestore.firestore().collection("users")
    
    public func getCurrentUIDData(completion: @escaping (_ currentUserData: UserModel) -> Void) {
        if let currentUID = self.authRef.currentUser?.uid {
            self.userInfoCollection.document(currentUID).getDocument { (document, error) in
                if let document = document {
                    if let userData = try? document.data(as: UserModel.self) {
                        completion(userData)
                    }
                } else if let error = error {
                    print("Error getting current UID data: \(error)")
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("No current UID")
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var userData: UserModel? = nil
    private let
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if let userData = self.userData { <-- safely unwrap data
                Text("Hey, \(userData.firstName) welcome!")
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            if self.userData == nil { <-- onAppear can call more than once
                self.udm.getCurrentUIDData { userData in
                   self.userData = userData  <-- pass data from func to view
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully this can point you in a better direction of how you should be getting and displaying data. Let me know if you have any further questions or issues.

Comment: There's an *assumption* here that the OP is storing the users id as the documentID. If they are not, then this code won't work and is not an answer (and they are using codable objects, also an unknown). That being said, it's a generally accepted practice to use the users uid as the document id instead of storing it in a uid field. Just wanted to add that clarification as we don't know the structure

Comment: @Jay good eye, I completely forgot to add the codable at first. And based on his code, he uses a whereField of "uid" on "users" collection. With that information it is safe to assume the documentID is the UID. Unless of course that is why he is not getting any data, I should have clarified that in my answer the documentID has to be each users UID.